# What is the efficient way to create Dataset for a given schema using scala?

Tags: apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset

I have a dataset with two columns `col1` and `col2` of array type of variable length. `col1` has the name of the field of the schema and `col2` has their corresponding values. Index of array from `col1` (which is the schema field name) determines the value from the `col2`. Schema fields will come from the distinct values of `col1` (c1, c2, c3, c4, c5, c6, and c7). Among c1 to c7, some of them are array type (say, c3, and c6), and others are string.

Sample input dataset:

```
     col1                         col2
--------------------------------------------------------------
[c1, c3, c6]                 [aaa, [ab, ac], [bc, bd]]
[c2, c3, c4, c5]             [bbb, [bb, bc], ccc, ddd]
[c4, c6, c7]                 [fff, [ss, pp, l], zzz]
```

Expected dataset:

```
c1         c2       c3        c4         c5        c6          c7
-------------------------------------------------------------------
aaa       null    [ab, ac]   null      null      [bc, bd]     null
null      bbb     [bb, bc]   ccc       ddd         null       null
null      null      null     fff       null      [ss, pp, l]  zzz
```